# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')'

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

This is the code. However I kept getting this error

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 7

Weirdly line 7 is the `CREATE TABLE academicnews( line. Which does not contain ')'` .

```
CREATE TABLE academicnews(
anewsID             INT             NOT NULL        PRIMARY KEY       AUTO_INCREMENT,
title               VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL,
anewsContent        TEXT            NOT NULL,
imagePath           VARCHAR(200)    NOT NULL,
timeNews            DATE            NOT NULL,
);  #Line 7
```

Comment: Why does adding comment like  --Comment  gives error as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get rid of the last comma. It is unnecessary and invalid.

```
CREATE TABLE academicnews(
anewsID             INT             NOT NULL        PRIMARY KEY       AUTO_INCREMENT,
title               VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL,
anewsContent        TEXT            NOT NULL,
imagePath           VARCHAR(200)    NOT NULL,
timeNews            DATE            NOT NULL, <-- HERE
);
```

It should be

```
CREATE TABLE academicnews(
anewsID             INT             NOT NULL        PRIMARY KEY       AUTO_INCREMENT,
title               VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL,
anewsContent        TEXT            NOT NULL,
imagePath           VARCHAR(200)    NOT NULL,
timeNews            DATE            NOT NULL
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error bcoz of an addition `comma`.

```
CREATE TABLE academicnews(
anewsID             INT             NOT NULL        PRIMARY KEY       AUTO_INCREMENT,
title               VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL,
anewsContent        TEXT            NOT NULL,
imagePath           VARCHAR(200)    NOT NULL,
timeNews            DATE            NOT NULL, <--- This is the error
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testinfo` (
  `id` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sl_no` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `p1` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `p2` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `p3` int(3)DEFAULT select [p1]+[p2],
  `mid` int(8) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `mid` (`mid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```